# MediaElement in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, media, mediaelement

In windows phone 7 .. I used medialement element to play mp3 audio from an URL ..

the first time the audio plays without any failure.. but when set the source for the second time it throws the following exception:

```
AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR
```

What could be the problem

Note: I tried to play the same audio file but also it didn't work.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide the code you are using to play the MediaElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the URL Limitations in Silverlight. A full description of the answer is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008(VS.95).aspx

> For security reasons, the Silverlight runtime restricts access to
>   certain classes of URLs from the WebClient and HTTP classes in the
>   System.Net namespace. There are similar access restrictions applied by
>   the runtime to other classes including the Image and MediaElement
>   classes in the System.Windows.Controls namespace. The runtime also
>   applies access restrictions to XAML source files and font files based
>   on the class of URL. These restrictions are implemented in the
>   Silverlight 2 and later runtime. The connections affected are access
>   to cross-zone, cross-domain, and cross-scheme URLs. These restrictions
>   are designed to prevent networking threats (for example, threats based
>   on a Silverlight application run from an internet server getting
>   access to resources on a local intranet server).